# O Complexity of Matlab Tables

Tags: matlab, time-complexity, matlab-table

For matlab tables, what is the complexity of look up times? I would think it is O(n) since it looks like it is going through every single entry. However, I could see it running in O(1). Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Section of the code we are trying to speed up is below.

```
x = All_InnerAir;
nrow = size(x,1);
T = table(zeros(nrow,1),zeros(nrow,1),'VariableNames',{'CubeSide' 'Direction'});
x = [x T];
    for i=1:nrow;
        if x{i,7}<320 && x{i,7}>160 % right side = 1 (compare x)
            x{i,13} = 1;
        elseif x{i,7}>-320 && x{i,7}<-160 % left side = 2
            x{i,13} = 2;
        elseif x{i,8}<335 && x{i,8}>160  % back side = 3 (compare y)
            x{i,13} = 3;
        elseif x{i,8}>-335 && x{i,8}<-160 % front side = 4
            x{i,13} = 4;
        elseif x{i,9}<600 && x{i,9}>160  % top side = 5 (compare z)
            x{i,13} = 5;
        elseif x{i,9}>-600 && x{i,9}<-160 % bottom side = 6
            x{i,13} = 6;
        elseif x{i,13} == 0
            x{i,13} = 99999;    % Error check
        end
    end
    for i=1:nrow;
        if x{i,13} == 1  && x{i,4} > 0 % right side (1) away
            x{i,14} = -1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 1 && x{i,4} < 0 % right side towards center
            x{i,14} = 1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 2  && x{i,4} > 0 % left side (2) towards center
            x{i,14} = 1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 2 && x{i,4} < 0 %left side away
            x{i,14} = -1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 3  && x{i,5} > 0 % back side (3) away
            x{i,14} = -1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 3 && x{i,5} < 0 % back side towards center
            x{i,14} = 1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 4  && x{i,5} > 0 % front side (4) towards center
            x{i,14} = 1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 4 && x{i,5} < 0 % front side away
            x{i,14} = -1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 5  && x{i,6} > 0 % top side (5) away
            x{i,14} = -1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 5 && x{i,6} < 0 % top side towards center
            x{i,14} = 1;  
        elseif x{i,13} == 6  && x{i,6} > 0 % bottom side (6) towards center
            x{i,14} = 1;
        elseif x{i,13} == 6 && x{i,6} < 0 % bottom side away
            x{i,14} = -1;  
        elseif x{i,14} == 0 
            x{i,14} = 99999;    % Error Check
        end
    end
All_InnerAir = x;
```

Comment: What kind of lookup? Can you post a code example for clarity?

Comment: If you are using inbuilt functions, generally they are as optimized as the human knowledge in the year 2015 allows it. So if there is any possible way of making that run in O(1), then Matlab does it.

Comment: What code are using to measure the complexity? Could it be that you are testing very small tables? Also, do you mean `table` data type or just a numeric array?

Comment: table as the data type.

Comment: And a section of the code is up. I'm mostly concerned about the x{i,#} lines

Comment: If you are looking for a way to improve code speed, please at least include (some code that creates) a mockup table of the right size. Otherwise any optimization is purely theoretical.

Comment: You could try to make use of the 'parfor' loop, if its only about speeding up things. See here: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html (or simply try to replace 'for' with 'parfor' and see if the matlab compilers is happy).